# In log4net, how do I use the same appender, just with a different file name?

Tags: logging, log4net

I have a log4net file appender configured that all my log files should use:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="..\Logs\"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <datePattern type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="yyyyMMdd'.Log'"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[%date][%-5level][%logger] %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

The directory and date pattern is hard-coded. I have different loggers that should use the exact same configuration, but just with a different folder name.

For now, I ended up copying and pasting each block into a new appender, but is there a way to configure log4net to 'share' a common appender's settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible unless you configure log4net programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the config does need to be accomplished programmatically:

Call this before Configure():

```
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["SysLogFileName"] = syslogFileName;
```

Use this to update:

```
    public static void ChangeSyslogFile(string syslogFileName)
    {
        var hier = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;
        if (hier == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to change Syslog filename, null hierarchy");
            return;
        }
        var sysLogAppender =
            (RollingFileAppender) hier.GetAppenders().
                                      First(appender => appender.Name.Equals("SimulatedSysLogFile", 
                                          StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (null == sysLogAppender)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to change Syslog filename, appender not found");
            return;
        }
        sysLogAppender.File = syslogFileName;
        sysLogAppender.ActivateOptions(); 
    }
```

This is my config:

```
  <appender name="SimulatedSysLogFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">                 
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{SysLogFileName}" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt} %message %newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I need to be able to change the XML config on the fly, this solution does not work for me, but it might be exactly what someone else is looking for.

Comment: Ah, I see. Hopefully it will be helpful.  I am sure that I used a least a couple stackoverflow and other posts to get it working so this is the right place for it.  Cheers.